# Conver ASCII to plain text in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ascii

I have some vars with sentences in them, where I have to replace the apostrophe with `"&#39;"`. However, I'd like for a user to be able to tweet these out. When I add them to the tweet, it obviously just writes the ASCII code out as if it were normal English. Is there a way to convert these into proper punctuation before they're sent off to be tweeted?

Comment: That's not an "ASCII code," that's an HTML [decimal character reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-references).  You don't have to use the reference, you can just use `'`. There's no reason you can't have a `'` in a variable in JavaScript, and no reason you can't have a `'` in HTML text literally (rather than using the character reference).  But if you have a variable where you've done that, e.g.: `var foo = "That&#39;s an interesting thing to do.";` you can convert it to `'` via `replace`: `foo = foo.replace(/&#39;/g, "'");`

Comment: You're right, I was setting my vars up to have sentences in that begin and end with single quote marks rather than proper quotation marks, so it was confusing things. Thanks for pointing out my error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you could do it like this:

```
$('<div>').html("&#39;").text();
```

If you are using plain JavaScript, you could do it like this:

```
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = "&#39;";
element.textContent;
```

---

**Here are two runnable examples:**

jQuery:

```js
console.log($('<div>').html("&#39;").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

plain JavaScript:

```js
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = "&#39;";
console.log(element.textContent);
```